# Gretty configuration: problems fast-reload

Tags: gradle, jetty, gretty

I 've a web of application with embedded jetty (it's a gradle application) and I'm using [gretty](https://github.com/akhikhl/gretty) plugin.
I need fast reload for all 'static' application resources so I've configured gretty this in the build.gradle:

```
gretty {
    serverConfigFile = file("$rootDir/jetty.xml")
    contextConfigFile = file("$rootDir/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jetty-env.xml")
    fastReload = "true"
 }
```

The problem is that when I change, for example, an .html file, the traces the beginning of the execution daemon appear in the console but suddenly an exception throws and it's not changed.

```
org.akhikhl.gretty.JettyScannerManager$1@3e199dce failed on '[/home/vjsantojaca/Developer/Relevante/relevanteme-web-2.0/src/main/webapp/templates/header.jsp]
java.net.ConnectException: Conexión rehusada
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:244)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:102)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:194)
    at org.akhikhl.gretty.ServiceProtocol.send(ServiceProtocol.groovy:42)
    at org.akhikhl.gretty.ServiceProtocol$send$1.call(Unknown Source)
 ...
```

What can be the reason?

Comment: Are there errors below these lines?  It is failing to open a socket, don't know if that socket is where it is sending to refresh the static resources.

Comment: I've a problem with the jetty-env.xml.